# ASP.NET WebForms ko.mapping is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I cannot for the life of me figure out why ko.mapping is undefined.

I'm using the following JS libraries:

- jquery
- knockout
- knockout.mapping
- moment
- fullcalendar
- datatables
- datatables.columnFilter
- dataTables.scroller
- jquery.blockUI

I've tried the following (with hard refreshes after each change):

1. I've reordered the js files in the head every combination I can. (Thought maybe the on ready function was being called prior to the library loading)
2. Removed the other JS libraries (thought maybe there was some sort of conflict)
3. Swapped local file for a cdn reference to knockout-mapping
4. Created a new file and put knockout and knockout mapping in it and added it to the scripts to include
5. Changed the file name of the combined file to not include the word mapping(I thought maybe there was something funky about the file name)

Interestingly enough the only two ways I could get this working were

If I copy-pasted the knockout-mapping into the knockout library file(but a new file with a different name but the exact same content did not).

OR

What I actually ended up doing was the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    .
    .
    .
    var loadKnockoutMapping = function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = '/cstm/JavaScript/knockout.mapping-2.4.1.js';
        document.body.appendChild(s);

        var callbackTimer = setInterval(function () {
            var mappingIsDefined = false;
            try {
                mappingIsDefined = (ko.mapping !== undefined);
            } catch (e) { }

            if (mappingIsDefined) {
                clearInterval(callbackTimer);
                setupRequestableAssignmentData(); //uses ko.mapping.fromJS function
            }
        }, 100);
    }
    loadKnockoutMapping();
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here? I even tried just not adding a new script element to the page and just a timeout function to wait until ko.mapping is not undefined but that didn't work either ko.mapping never ended up being defined to anything.

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but I'm afraid without a repro (which -I know- is *really* hard to create for this kind of problem) we can only resort to guessing as to what the issue is.

Comment: Have you tried bumping up the timer? Maybe 100ms is not long enough to wait.

Comment: @Jeroen yeah, I think the most frustrating part of this is I've used the same combination of libraries on a different page in the same project. Maybe I can rebuild the page piece by piece to see if I can find the root cause and then post the solution here.

Comment: @JeffMercado the callback runs every 100ms until it finds ko mapping as defined, so increasing that timer just makes it check less often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are "re-inventing" the wheel here. There is a an excellent library for this. http://requirejs.org/

That will handle the script-loading for you.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery.js',
        knockout: 'libs/knockout.js',
        knockoutMapping: 'libs/knockoutMapping.js'
    }
    shim: {
        'knockout': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        }
    }
});


require(["jquery","knockout","knockoutMapping",function($,ko,mapping){
    console.log($,ko,mapping);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is another good solution to fix the problem at hand but really I would prefer to be able to include the file on the page. As the solution I came up with and this one would both be one offs and not consistent with the way any of our other pages are. Thanks anyway though, I may switch over my hack to this one